# How do I scrape <div> tags using Python?

Tags: python, html

I'm trying to scrape data from a listing website with the following html structure

```
 <div class="ListingCell-AllInfo ListingUnit" data-bathrooms="1" data-bedrooms="1" data-block="21st Floor" data-building_size="31" data-category="condominium" data-condominiumname="Twin Lakes Countrywoods" data-price="6000000" data-subcategories='["condominium","single-bedroom"]'>
      <div class="ListingCell-TitleWrapper">
       <h3 class="ListingCell-KeyInfo-title" title="Twin Lakes Countrywoods 1BR Unit for Sale, Tagaytay">
        <a class="js-listing-link" data-position="8" data-sku="CD5E17CED0347ECPH" href="https://www.lamudi.com.ph/twin-lakes-countrywoods-1br-unit-for-sale-tagaytay-2.html" target="_blank" title="Twin Lakes Countrywoods 1BR Unit for Sale, Tagaytay">
         Twin Lakes Countrywoods 1BR Unit for Sale, Tagaytay
        </a>
       </h3>
       <div class="ListingCell-KeyInfo-address ellipsis">
        <a class="js-listing-link ellipsis" data-position="8" data-sku="CD5E17CED0347ECPH" href="https://www.lamudi.com.ph/twin-lakes-countrywoods-1br-unit-for-sale-tagaytay-2.html" target="_blank" title="Twin Lakes Countrywoods 1BR Unit for Sale, Tagaytay">
         <span class="icon-pin">
         </span>
         <span>
          Tagaytay Hi-Way

                                Dayap Itaas, Laurel
         </span>
        </a>
       </div>
```

What I want to get is the info beside  <div class="ListingCell-AllInfo ListingUnit"... which are data-bathrooms, data-bedrooms, data-block, etc.

I tried to scrape it using Python BeautifulSoup

```
details = container.find('div',class_="ListingCell-AllInfo ListingUnit").text if container.find('div',class_="ListingCell-AllInfo ListingUnit") else "-"
```

It's been returning "-" for all listings. Complete newbie here!

Comment: Please reduce and enhance this into the expected [MRE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).  Show where the intermediate results deviate from the ones you expect.  Also repeat [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) from the
[intro tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour).  We expect  you to work with available tutorials and examples before posting here.  There are many available resources that show you how to extract a particular tag; Stack Overflow is not intended to replace those.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Beautiful soup that would be better it has alway worked for me .

```
 req = Request("put your url here",headers={'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0'})
 webpage = urlopen(req).read()
 soup = BeautifulSoup(webpage)

 title = soup.find_all('tag you want to scrape', class_='class of that tag')
```

visit the link for more info : https://pypi.org/project/beautifulsoup4/

Answer (score 0):

there ! You could use regular expression to solve your issue

I have introduced a few comment in my solution but for more information,
take a look at the [official documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html)
or read [this](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html)

```
import re # regular expression module

txt = """insert your html here"""

# we create a regex patern called p1 and this that will match a string starting with
# <div class="ListingCell-AllInfo ListingUnit"
# following by anything (any character) found 0 or more times
# and the string must end by '>'
p1 = re.compile(r'<div class="ListingCell-AllInfo ListingUnit".*>')

# findall return a list of strings that matches the patern p1 in txt
ls = p1.findall(txt)

# now, what you want is the data, so we can create another patern where the word
# "data" will be found

# match string starting with data following by '-' then by 0 or more alphanumeric char
# then with '=' then with any character found in after the '=' that is not not
# a space, a tab 

p2 =  re.compile(r'(data-\w*=\S*)')
data = p2.findall(ls[0])

print(data)
```

Note : Don't be scared by the funky symbols they look way worse than what they truly are